# How to activate GRPC PHP extension via Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, grpc

I have this Dockerfile. When I try to run it, in the Composer Update line it returns an error, that extensions are not installed.

That is because of GRPC not being activated on the php.ini

My question is, how can I activated it via terminal?

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY . ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q nodejs npm curl unzip git rake ruby-ronn zlib1g-dev libpng-dev && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install php7.2=dev php-pear phpunit
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN pecl install grpc
RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g gulp-cli
RUN composer update
RUN gulp --env=production
EXPOSE 80 443
```

Answer (score 6):

you forgot to activate the grcp extension ,you can use the code under the comment `#install protoc` to activated,and you will get message if it has activated or not by `RUN php -r "echo extension_loaded('grpc') ? 'yes' : 'no';"`
I think this way is better and more concise:

```
FROM php:7-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q git rake ruby-ronn zlib1g-dev && apt-get clean
# install composer
RUN cd /usr/local/bin && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN cd /usr/local/bin && mv composer.phar composer
RUN pecl install grpc
#install protoc
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/protoc && \
    curl -L https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.2.0/protoc-3.2.0-linux-x86_64.zip > /tmp/protoc/protoc.zip && \
    cd /tmp/protoc && \
    unzip protoc.zip && \
    cp /tmp/protoc/bin/protoc /usr/local/bin && \
    cd /tmp && \
    rm -r /tmp/protoc && \
    docker-php-ext-enable grpc

RUN php -r "echo extension_loaded('grpc') ? 'yes' : 'no';"
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install
RUN npm install 
RUN npm install -g gulp-cli
RUN gulp --env=production
EXPOSE 8181
```

Comment: Add some explanation for your code would be preferred